# Upgrade network configuration after chaincode modification on hyperledger Fabric blockchain

Tags: node.js, go, hyperledger-fabric

I am working with this blockchain application for medics traceability (https://github.com/rastringer/medication-blockchain) based on hyperledger fabric blockchain.

It's exactly the same app as this project (https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app) except that this project is for tuna traceability.

I modify the chaincode file (the file is "drug-chaincode.go"), and now apparently I need to reconfigure all my network in "basic-network" folder so that the modification is add, but I don't how I can do this.

I tried to follow this link without results ([How to upgrade a chaincode after modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330576/how-to-upgrade-a-chaincode-after-modification))

Anyhelp is welcome, thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

if u r trying to build hyperledger project similar to drug-app.  Then do following things:

```
Delete node_modules:
drug-blockchain/drug-app/node_modules
```

Then change every parameter which states the drug blockchain, basically u have to change parameters to Yours on following sources:

```
drug-chaincode.go
startFabric.sh
server.js
routes.js
registerUser.js
registerAdmin.js
package.json
controller.js
recordDrug.js
queryDrug.js
queryAllDrug.js
changeDrugHolder.js
app.ja
index.html
```

In the end re-run the network:

```
cd drug-blockchain/drug-app
$./startFabric.sh
$npm install -g
$node registerAdmin.js
$node registerUser.js
$node server.js
```

if u do change parameters properly, it should work fine, otherwise recheck, there shouldn't be any data of previous drug-blockchain!

Comment: This solution not resolve the problem, sadly. I can run the application without problem, I can do the 4 principal action with the application etc... and now I only modify the "drug-chaincode.go" file at the part with the 10 test data to get new data (for example I just changed some 'manufacturer' value or some 'older' value). And after that when I restart the server, remove 'node-modules' folder, reinstall node module etc ... the new value is not added (it's still the old value)

Comment: I found the solution at this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855723/hyperledger-fabric-chaincode-not-updated